# Executing local PHP file with Axios

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I am trying to execute a local php file from the client with axios get. This is most likely not achievable from what I found out, except that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719086/axios-get-from-local-php-just-returns-code-instead-of-executing) post has an answear that helped, unfortunately it is too vague for me to understand what he really ment by "environment hasn't got PHP installed", but it gave me hope. The OP had pretty much an identical issue like me.

The functionality of my php code is this - after taking the params from the get url it downloads a file in the same directory as the php file. I'm doing this, so I can have local access to the downloaded file in my client. Also I am doing it like that because I don't have access to the server side of the project.

If this is not possible after all, I found out that running my project throughout the xampp Apache server could work for me, but not sure if it is going to be ideal. I already confirmed that the php code works by running it trough Apache and using axios get to execute it, but I need the downloaded file in my project's local dir.

Comment: Your client will need to have PHP installed, they'll have to put the file in the right place, and you'll need to know the FQDN or IP address of their local server. None of this is likely to be very user-friendly to get going.

Comment: There is probably a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.  What is you end goal or reason for wanting to do this?

Comment: The file im downloading is a publication.xod and the only way of it reaching to the client so I can render it through a webviewer is via API. @ceejayoz thank you for your answear. I actually understand now what he ment by that. Do you think if I can make it work with the Apache server, It will have the same result when it gets build for production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well till this current moment there is no way to execute php file in the client without a server. But building and implementing my project into xampp Apache server did the trick better than I expected. It managed to help me simulate the path of the downloaded file so I can access it.

As @ceejayoz mentioned in his comment "*they'll have to put the file in the right place, and you'll need to know the FQDN or IP address of their local server*" so that the connection between the file from the server and the client has no issues.